# FlexSlider with WordPress Gallery

Tags: wordpress, flexslider

How do you get FlexSlider working with a WordPress Gallery?

I'm creating a custom theme and, ideally, I'd like every gallery in the theme to be automatically turned into a FlexSlider image rotator, without using another plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at t31os answer on a similar question: [How to customise the output of the WP image gallery shortcode from a plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4358/16034).

You would be doing is overriding the core gallery_shortcode function (line 702 of wp-includes/media.php) with your returned `$output`, place his code or similar in functions.php in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you did not want to use another plugin, but i would recommend trying out the advanced custom fields plugin with the gallery extension.

With that its very easy to create custom galleries with your own markup. [Check it out here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/gallery/)

It certanly solved my problems with integrating the fresco lightbox like i wanted it to be. Just some sample outtake code to show you how to use the custom fields:

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
            <li>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                <p class="flex-caption"><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 6 years old, but I recently needed to do this on a WP 5.0+ install and it proved harder than expected, because of the block editor, aka. Gutenberg.

I solved it by, probably taking a significant performance hit (correct me, if I'm wrong), using `parse_blocks` and `render_block` to manually re-render `the_content`.

This goes in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
<?php

function filter_gallery_blocks($content) {
    global $post;

    if ( has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
        $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
        $new_content = '';

        foreach ( $blocks as $key => $block ) {
            if ( $block['blockName'] === 'core/gallery' ) {
                $rendered_block = render_block($block);

                // do whatever replacement you like with the block HTML

                // in case of Flexslider I needed the following 3 lines
                $rendered_block = str_replace('<figure>', '', $rendered_block);
                $rendered_block = str_replace('</figure>', '', $rendered_block);
                $rendered_block = str_replace('wp-block-gallery', 'wp-block-gallery slides', $rendered_block);

                $new_content .= '<div class="gallery">'.$rendered_block.'</div>';
                continue;
            }

            // else just pass through
            $rendered_block = render_block($block);
            $new_content .= $rendered_block;
        }

        return $new_content;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_gallery_blocks', -5);

?>
```